# Magento 2.3 - Error related to Amasty shopby while RUNNING setup di:compile

Tags: magento2, php, magento2.3, di, amasty

> MiBPHP Fatal error:  Declaration of
>   Amasty\Shopby\Model\Source\Attribute\Extended::toOptionArray() must be
>   compatible with
>   Amasty\Shopby\Model\Source\Attribute::toOptionArray($boolean = 1) in
>   /home/ubuntu/environment/the-new-craftsmen/app/code/Amasty/Shopby/Model/Source/Attribute/Extended.php
>   on line 28

```
public function toOptionArray()
    {
        $allOption = [[
            'value' => self::ALL,
            'label' => strval(__('All Attributes'))
        ]];
        return array_merge($allOption, parent::toOptionArray());
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

The declaration of a `toOptionArray()` function must match with its parent

Try to use `$boolean = 1` in your child function like this

> app/code/Amasty/Shopby/Model/Source/Attribute/Extended.php

```
public function toOptionArray($boolean = 1)
{
    $allOption = [[
        'value' => self::ALL,
        'label' => strval(__('All Attributes'))
    ]];
    return array_merge($allOption, parent::toOptionArray());
}
```

Or Remove `$boolean = 1` from parent file's `toOptionArray()` function

> app/code/Amasty/Shopby/Model/Source/Attribute.php

```
/**
 * Options getter
 *
 * @return array
 */
public function toOptionArray()
{
    $optionArray = [];
    $arr = $this->toArray();
    foreach($arr as $value => $label){
        $optionArray[] = [
            'value' => $value,
            'label' => $label
        ];
    }
    return $optionArray;
}
```

Hope this will help you!

Comment: Let me know if it helps, thanks. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Give a try to add a parameter in the file `app/code/Amasty/Shopby/Model/Source/Attribute/Extended.php`

```
public function toOptionArray($boolean = 1)
    {
        $allOption = [[
            'value' => self::ALL,
            'label' => strval(__('All Attributes'))
        ]];
        return array_merge($allOption, parent::toOptionArray());
    }
```